# On NetBeans platform, have both primary and secondary preferences panel

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

In my application based on the NetBeans platform (RELEASE801) I want to extend the preferences panel by a primary panel and some secondary panels, which I want to appear in another primary panel.

Basically, what I have is 1) my primary panel:

```
@OptionsPanelController.TopLevelRegistration(
    categoryName = "Snap",
    iconBase = "...",
    keywords = "...",
    keywordsCategory = "..."
)
public final class SnapOptionsPanelController extends OptionsPanelController {
    [...]
}
```

2) a package-info.java, which I expect to be interpreted as the second primary panel:

```
@OptionsPanelController.ContainerRegistration(
    id = "myId",
    categoryName = "Snap",
    iconBase = "...",
    keywords = "...",
    keywordsCategory = "...")
package org.esa.snap.gui.preferences.uibehavior;

import org.netbeans.spi.options.OptionsPanelController;
```

3) a class for my secondary panel, which I want to appear below the second primary panel:

```
@OptionsPanelController.SubRegistration(location = "SnapPreferences",
                                        displayName ="...",
                                        keywords = "...",
                                        keywordsCategory = "...",
                                        id = "UiBehavior")
public final class UiBehaviorPanelController extends OptionsPanelController {
    [...]
}
```

Running the application and opening the preferences view, everything looks as expected first. But after I click on the Icon of the primary panel once, I cannot go back to the secondary container -- the content stays the same. Clicking the built-in icons works as expected.

I also observe that only the repaint()-method of the JComponent of the primary panel is called, not that of the secondary.

Note: I am using the Maven nbm-plugin for building; anyway, I don't think the problem is related to that, since the generated Manifest file looks fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it: the value of `categoryName` must be different between the primary panel and the panel defined in package-info.java.